# How can I protect against cross-build injection and other dependancy management threats in Play Framework?

Tags: java, security, playframework, dependencies, dependency-management

I am using Play Framework's inbuilt dependancy management to download a library (HTMLUnit), to do this I add the dependancy to the build.sbt file like so:

`libraryDependencies += "net.sourceforge.htmlunit" % "htmlunit" % "2.20"`

The dependancy is then downloaded using Apache Ivy (via sbt) when I build the project.

How do I know that the downloaded dependancy is what it says it is, and also ensure it contains no malicious code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely the same as for other systems:

1) Do not use an automatic building. You can Download all libraries, verify them and put them into the "lib" folder.

2) Use local (or inner organization server) repository. You need to download and check every dependency as in step "1" but you put them into the local repository and add this repository as source repository to the build.

See this document for the more detailed explanation https://www.fortify.com/downloads2/public/fortify_attacking_the_build.pdf

It's pretty old but looks correct.

Comment: thanks for your response, how do I verify a dependancy? HTMLUnit is available on [source forge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/files/htmlunit/), if I download it from here and place it in the lib folder how do I then ensure the manually downloaded file is authentic? also, reading things like this seem to steer me away from source forge: [Warning: Don’t Download Software From SourceForge If You Can Help It](http://www.howtogeek.com/218764/warning-don%E2%80%99t-download-software-from-sourceforge-if-you-can-help-it/)

Comment: In a short: You never can be sure until test downloaded lib by your own (your security department). So - if you are small project, like 1-30 person, then just trust maven, or what you use (like millions do) if you are big project and you need 100% security - you need to assign few people to check every library that you use on suspicious code, and put then them into the safe intranet repository. Please, read the document I linked. It contains a broad answer to your question.